# Facebook login with JS SDK returns "unknown" on facebook built-in browser

Tags: javascript, android, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I'm having an issue with a facebook app on Android 4.3 (and maybe other versions but 5 & 6 seem okay).

It's a web app, users can share pictures and their friends can go and vote for it, but they have to be logged in to the app. I'm using the JS SDK. 
Facebook opens the link in it's own browser and the FB.login seem to fail. I have an "unknown" status so I try a FB.login and nothing seems to happen... 
If I open the same link in chrome, everything works fine, Facebook asks for the permissions (after i got a "not_authorized" status) and I can vote.

Is there a way to make it work with the old versions of the facebook browser ? Or maybe a way to know the user is using this old browser so I can put an error message?

See comments for the fiddle

```js
// Rate a picture
function rateApic(domLink) {
  var $link = $(domLink);
  $.ajax({
    url: '/rateAPicture',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
      id: $link.attr('data-entry')
    },
    success: function(result, status) {
      var content = result.message;
      switch (result.returnCode) {
        case 0: // OK
          $link.parent().find('.nbRatings').html(result.nbRatings); // rate number +1
          popupManager(content); // display success message
          break;
        case 1: // Not logged in
          loginFb('rateAphoto', $link);
          break;
        default:
          popupManager(content); // display error message
      }
    },
    error: function(result, status, error) {},
    complete: function(result, status) {}
  });
};

// Check user login state
function checkLoginState() {
  var status = "";
  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    status = response.status;
  });
  return status;
}

// Connect to facebook app
function loginFb(redirectUrl, object) {
  var loginState = checkLoginState();

  if (loginState === 'unknown' || loginState === "not_authorized" || loginState == undefined) {
    // within Facebook's app built-in browser on Adroid (4.3 & 5.1.1 and other versions but 6.0.1 is okay) 
    // loginState is always unknown 
    FB.login(function(response) {
      if (response.status === 'connected') {
        loginToApp(redirectUrl, object);
      };
    }, {
      scope: 'public_profile,email,user_friends'
    });
  } else if (loginState === 'connected') {
    loginToApp(redirectUrl, object);
  }
}

// Connect to local app 
function loginToApp(redirectUrl, object) {
  // Connect to local app with facebook informations
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a onclick="rateApic(this);" data-entry="42" href="#">Like</a>
```

Comment: Would you create jsfiddle for this

Comment: @ParagBhayani : 
I created one here : https://jsfiddle.net/evj3tw9L/3/
It's not a working one because it needs facebook SDK to work but you can see the code.
I added comments to show where the problem is...

Comment: would you please comment in english ... and send the updated fiddle

Comment: @ParagBhayani Here : https://jsfiddle.net/bhyz5es1/2/
sorry...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook says it's not a bug (it's for security reasons) and they won't fix it so...

This is what I did :

```
if (loginState === 'unknown' || loginState === "not_authorized" || loginState == undefined) {
    FB.login(function(response) {
      if (response.status === 'connected') {
        loginToApp(redirectUrl, object);
      };
    }, {
      scope: rights
    });

    if (checkLoginState() === 'unknown') {
      // Redirect to the login page
      $.ajax({
        url: '/GetFacebookAppId',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(result, status) {
          window.location.href = 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?' + 'client_id=' + result.appId + '&redirect_uri=' + redirectUrl + '&scope=' + rights;
        },
        error: function(result, status, error) {},
        complete: function(result, status) {}
      });
    }
 }
```

So anytime the FB.login is not working and the FB.getLoginStatus returns "unknown", I redirect the user to the login page.